# Cannot create or open projects in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I get this error when trying to create or open existing projects, VS 2012 on Windows 8

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried to remove and reinstall entity framework, but the installer tells me my computer already has it installed.

Comment: I'd suggest a complete removal and reinstall.  Maybe someone else will have a quicker solution.

Comment: tried that, didnt help

Comment: Maybe try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/EN-US#Force .  I'm assuming that something about the old, bad setup is left behind, and needs eliminating.